# Magento 2 : textarea height automatic set large in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, ui-form

In magento 2 admin, I want to expandable textarea height using xml. How to do that?

I tried this code. But, it's not working.

```
<field name="comment">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Comment</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">comment</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">comment</item>
                    <item name="cols" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

**Actual Result :**

[image]

**Expected Result :**

[image]

Comment: what is your expected output here?

Comment: As like screenshot.

Comment: ahh.. I think you can define row instead `<item name="rows" xsi:type="number">200</item>`

Comment: I mean together with the column you have to define the rows as well

Comment: Nope. Still, it's not working.

Comment: what output did you get now?

Comment: Please check my updated question. Right now, It's display Actual Result. But, I need Expected Result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93133/discussion-between-magefms-and-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd).

Comment: do you want this as wyswyg editir or not?

Comment: No. Just by textarea.

Comment: Can you tell me where you put this ? Does it is your custom form of what?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. have you try my solution?

Comment: Thanks for accepting answer & upvote  +1 for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To increase the height of text-area use `<item name="rows" xsi:type="number">60</item>` insted of `<item name="cols" xsi:type="number">200</item>`

But the above code is not working as expected and not increase the height of text-area because of Magento CSS issue. to check inspect element and find class `.admin__control-textarea` you can see css like below.

```
.admin__control-textarea {
   height: 8.48rem;
   line-height: 1.18;
   padding-top: .8rem;
   resize: vertical;
}
```

In the above CSS you can see CSS `height: 8.48rem;` just remove this CSS and see your code is working fine so reason for this CSS your code is not working.

To resolve the above issue try with below way :

Add item to your field `<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">md_product_label_uploader</item>` for add custom class to your field and apply custom CSS to this field and it will be working fine.

**Note :**  This is [default Magento bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22771) I submitted an issue on GitHub.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I tried his code in my custom ui form and it works...

Comment: no I mean his code which he says is not working is working for me. so it is not a default magento bug

Comment: @magefms check here it is default Magento bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22771 
I have reported this bug on GitHub

Comment: The height issue appears to have been fixed in Magento, but does anyone have a clue how to pass attributes like `rows` in custom widget parameters?